# How to determine the numer of days between two dates?

Tags: python, date

I'm having trouble figuring out how to check if a date is greater than 3 (or any number) of days. Please excuse the messy code, I am just trying to get it working before I go back and clean things up. This is what I have:

```
ticket_list = data['tickets']

tickets = 0

for t in ticket_list:
    status = ticket_list[tickets]['status']
    subject = ticket_list[tickets]['subject']
    if status == "pending":
        ticket_id = str(ticket_list[tickets]['id'])
        ticket_metrics_url = "https://{domain}.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/" + ticket_id + "/metrics.json"
        ticket_metrics = requests.get(ticket_metrics_url, auth=(user, pwd))
        metrics_data = ticket_metrics.json()
        updated_time = metrics_data['ticket_metric']['requester_updated_at']
        updated_time = updated_time[0:10:1]
        now = str(datetime.now())
        now = now[0:10:1]
        if now > updated_time:
            print("We are closing this ticket.")

    tickets += 1
```

So I am pulling a list of tickets, checking if they are pending, then if they are pending, I want to see if the last date the person responded was older than 3 days. If it is older than 3 days, I want to close the ticket. If it isn't over 3 days, I want to reply asking for an update.

I just can't figure out how to make that last `if` statement checks if the ticket is over 3 days old. Since it is a string, I don't think I can perform any calculations on it, but I also don't know how to turn it back into an `int` that I could work with. Any ideas?

Oh, to clarify, I turned the `updated_time` variable into a string so that I could try to match the format that I would get with `datetime.now()`. The `update_time` variable gives me a readout like this: `2020-11-17T20:15:13Z`

Preferably I'd like to check if it is older than 72 hours, but I wasn't sure how to do that either.

Comment: Convert the two date strings into `datetime` instances, then you can subtract them and get a [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects). You can check the `days` attribute of that.

Comment: @martineau - Thank you SO MUCH!!!! That did it. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Jon: Glad to hear my summary of what to do was useful.